# Passing JSON Array to Spring Controller

Tags: ajax, spring, post

I have Spring Boot 2.1.3 + thymeleaf webapp. I'm trying to pass a json array to controller by ajax POST. The JSON array is built as follow:

```
var obj = [];
$('#fornitori-table').find('tr').each(function () {
  var row = $(this);
  if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
     var cellObj = row.find('td:eq(1)');
     if (cellObj.length > 0) obj.push({ idFurn : cellObj[0].innerText });
     }
});
```

Now if I pass *obj* array through GET as follows:

```
location.href = "/sendRdo/"+encodeURI(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

to controller:

```
@GetMapping("/sendRdo/{idS}")
public String sendRdo(@PathVariable JSONArray obj, Model model) {
....
}
```

all works well.. if I try to pass it with ajax post:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/sendRdo",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(obj), 
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(data) {

    }
  });
```

I got always *com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException* error unless I put Object as received type in the controller:

```
public String sendRdo(@RequestBody Object obj, Model model) {
}
```

If I debug and point the obj variable I see LinkedHashMap.. but if I put Map<> instead of Object I got the error above.

I'm using:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180813</version>
</dependency>
```

for json

Can you help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution (without creating a pojo):

```
function foo() {
  var obj=[];
  obj.push({id : 1});
  obj.push({id : 2});
  $.ajax({
       type: "post",
       url: "/test",
       contentType: "application/json",
       dataType:"json",
       data: JSON.stringify(obj),
       success: function(result) {

       }
  });
}
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/test")
String test(@RequestBody Object obj) {
    List<Map<String,Integer>> list = (ArrayList)obj;
    list.forEach(m -> m.forEach( (k,v) -> System.out.println("key: "+k+" value:"+v)) );
    return "someview";
}
```

hope helps.